# How to test for upgrade lock in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, concurrency, locking

Let's suppose I have:

```
session.Get<User>(id, LockMode.Upgrade)
```

First thread goes through. Second blocks. I would like to test for this lock and exit if locked.

How would I go about this?

Comment: It does work actually. It throws on lock, which is good enough. Please turn your comment into an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LockMode.UpgradeNoWait` (only supported if your SQL server supports it) ?

Alternatively you can use a transaction timeout to achieve a similar thing, but with some longer delay.

Comment: NHibernate supports this in its latest versions: https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect/MsSql2005Dialect.cs